# Compare Django Count() to Integer

Tags: django, annotations

I am trying to get *True* or *False* if there are unanswered questions for a specific topic.

I tried something along the lines of:
The following code does not work for me. It seems like I cant compare `<type 'Count'>` with `<type 'int'>`.

```
Topic.objects.all().annotate(has_unanswered_questions = Count('question', filter = Q(question__status.text='open')) > 0)
```

Comment: `.annotate()` will return you a queryset of objects and then you need to access each of them and check by `has_unanswered_questions` to see the results. Can you show us your `models.py` and also explain clearly what you want to achieve.

Comment: I am trying to add a column with calculated values to a django_tables2 table, which can be filtered by Django-Filter (which does not work with @property).

The code above is just an example. Hence, there is no matching models.py. The code is much more complex in reality.

Comment: Can't you just add a boolean flag to your questions? It will be much more chep to query upon.

Comment: I solved the issue by using columns.BooleanColumn instead of columns.column.  Where I make use the fact that any positive number  is casted to True.

For any other comparison I would have had to write my own column class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to filter on your annotations:

```
Topic.objects.all()\
    .annotate(unanswered_questions=Count('question', filter=Q(question__status.text='open')))\
    .filter(unanswered_questions__gt=0)
```